# Future Method and Static Variables

Tags: apex, webservices, visual-workflow, future, invocable-method

I have a class that implements Process.Plugin. It calls the invoke method, which calls a future method, which calls a webservice. The returned value from the webservice should be the **output parameters**. My issue is the static variables do not seem to be retaining their value outside of the future method.

I assume this has something to do with Async vs Sync methods but if anyone could explain as to why the `result` variable isn't holding it's value after the webservice is completed, I would appreciate it!

```
global class FlowToWebservice_Class implements Process.Plugin {
   public static Map<String,Object> result;
   ...

global static Process.PluginResult invoke(Process.PluginRequest request){
    varProcessName = (String)request.inputParameters.get('varProcessName');
    varCreditReviewId = (String)request.inputParameters.get('varCreditReviewId');
    callWebService(varProcessName , varCreditReviewId);
    return new Process.PluginResult(result);//the value of `result` is null so this will never return output parameters
}

@future(callout=true)
global static void callWebService(String processName, String crId) {
    k = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, object> {'Parameters' => new Map<String, object> {'CreditReviewId' => crId},'RulesSet' => processName}); 
    req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpointURL);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(k);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setTimeout(120000);
    string d = getAuth();
    req.setheader('Authorization', d);
    try {
        Http h = new Http();
        res = h.send(req);
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            ....
        }
    }
    catch (System.CalloutException z) {
        system.debug('z: ' + z);
    }
    result = new Map<String,Object>();
    result.put('varResult',finalDecision);
    result.put('varROSID', relatedOppSearchId);
    result.put('varDeclineReason', declineReason);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Static variables in Apex only retain their value through the course of a single transaction. Future methods by nature execute in a separate transaction, which means that your static variables are reset. You cannot use static variables to return a value from a future method to the synchronous code that called it.

Comment: ah interesting. Thank you for the quick response and the explanation. Because I can't return on a `future` method, and the variables are reset every time the method runs, how would I return the output parameters to the flow? (I have to break out the methods like this because it is being called from a Trigger).

Comment: I am not a heavy user of Flows, so others might have a better architectural recommendation than I do. The only option that comes to my mind would be a Wait element in the Flow looking for a Platform Event that is later fired by your web service code.

But if you're calling this from a trigger, you won't be able to pause and wait for a webservice return anyway. Why not fire the future method straight from the trigger?

Comment: @DavidReed Do you  have any links where it says we can pause a flow to wait for platform events?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_flow.htm